# Client Player not moving - NetCode for Game objects - NetworkTransform

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking

when the host try to move it works perfectly fine, but on the client, the client player does not move

```
// Input system callback for movement
public void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext value)
{
    if (!IsOwner) return;
    // Read and normalize 2D movement input
    model.Movement2D = value.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    model.Movement2D.Normalize();

    // Set movement direction in the player's local space
    model.Direction = new Vector3(model.Movement2D.x, 0, model.Movement2D.y);
    model.Direction.Normalize();

    // Apply the movement
    controller.ApplyMovement();
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!IsOwner) return;
    // Apply gravity and movement in fixed intervals
    ApplyGravity();
    ApplyMovement();
}


// Apply player movement based on input
public void ApplyMovement()
{
    ApplyMovementServerRpc();
}


[ServerRpc(RequireOwnership =false)]
private void ApplyMovementServerRpc()
{
    
    model.IsWalking = model.Direction.x != 0 || model.Direction.z != 0;
    float currentSpeed = model.Speed * (model.IsRunning && !model.IsCrouching ? model.SpeedWhileRunningMultiplier : model.IsCrouching ? model.SpeedWhileCrouchingMultiplier : 1);

    Vector3 currentDirection = model.Direction;

    // If stamina consumption is required, handle it
    if (model.ShouldConsumeStamina)
    {
        HandleStaminaConsumption(currentSpeed);
    }

    // Rotate player based on camera angle if required
    RotatePlayerByCameraAngle(ref currentDirection);
    Debug.Log("mova desgraça");
    model.Controller.Move(currentDirection * currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: If it works on host but not on client, chances are your host code is wrong too but it works by virtue of handwaving it is the host. Best guess from the code you showed, 'OnMovement' is executed locally, 'ApplyMovement' can't really work since it takes the server version/ position that does not have the changes. Isn't there a network transform component that handles that for you?

Comment: sorrry im new to netcode, dont know much,  until now my movements i tested it on single player(when i did not have the netcode) right now im trying to adapt it, what should i do? i have the network transform in my player but i do nothing with it